# reactjs routes / virtual pages on apache server

Tags: reactjs, apache, react-router

**Scenario**

I am using `BrowserRouter` routes in my react app. So if my base were "localhost:3000/site1" then a virtual page might be "localhost:3000/site1/route1". This works fine in development but not on an apache server.

**The Problem**

I'm assuming that the react dev server always sends requests to the main index.js / router whereas on an apache server it's actually looking for a page called site1/route1. If I refresh a page while it's in a virtual location then I get a "Page not found" error from apache.

## Question

How do I get my virtual routes to work with my production react build when it's on a php server? Do I need to add some redirect magic via a `.htaccess` file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by using an apache friendly `.htaccess` file in my project folder

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  /([^/]+)/?$  [NC]
RewriteRule .*   rel-path/to/project/build/index.html  [L]
```

The "build" in my path is the build folder created by `npm run build` - part of the reason I put the .htaccess in my project folder is so if anyone peeks into my project folder they will immediately be sent to the build/index.html